# How to confirm if TDE is being applied on my datastax cassandra node?

Tags: encryption, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We started exploring TDE, went ahead creating tables with TDE enabled and loaded data.
I see SSTables on disk now which are probably encrypted.

Is there a way for me to see and verify that this indeed is encrypted and compare it with a similar (but non-TDE) table ?

I can't use nodetool or similar tools as they are not directly protected by TDE.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is just to use grep for text string that you insert into table.  Just go to data directory, find directory with table, and run:

```
cd _cassandra_data_dir_/keyspace_name/table_name-hash/
grep 'your_string' *-Data.db
```

please, note that because partition keys aren't encrypted, they still will be visible...

Comment: Perfect and elegant way !! Thank you Alex.